# Proving two inner products are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $A=I+\alpha B$ and $B$ is skew-symmetric, then is it true that $(Ax,x)=(x,x)$? My intuition says it is. If so, how to prove that?

Comment: This is equivalent to showing that $(Bx, x) = 0$ for $B$ skew-symmetric. Do you know how to write $x \cdot y$ in terms of matrix multiplication?

Comment: @JohnHughes could you elaborate?

Comment: It's because $(Ax,x)=(x,x)\Leftrightarrow ((A-I)x,x)=0\Leftrightarrow \overline \alpha(Bx,x)=0$,

Comment: @Matematleta what does that bar on $\alpha$ mean?